# Trouble Integrating MySQL 8.0 with MAMP for Joomla 5 on an Older iMac

Tags: mysql, joomla, mamp

I'm facing an issue with setting up Joomla 5 on an older iMac. We've always used Joomla 4, but the new Joomla 5 requires MySQL 8.0. Our iMac is not compatible with the latest version of MAMP, which complicates installing MySQL 8.0.

What we've tried:

- We installed MySQL 8.0 directly on the iMac.
- Attempted to configure MAMP to use this new MySQL version, but no success.
- Tried switching MySQL versions in MAMP Pro, but couldn't figure it out.
- Located the `my.cnf` file but unsure how to modify it for our needs.

We're stuck at this point. Our goal is to run Joomla 5 with MySQL 8.0 on our iMac using MAMP. Can someone guide us through the process of configuring MAMP (or MAMP Pro) to work with MySQL 8.0, or suggest an alternative solution?

Thanks by advance

Comment: From a we b application point of view, you just need to point it to the mysql v8 instance in its configuration. There is nothing you need to do on mamp level to make it work.